# How to prevent Blender from adding sharp edges when editing UV

Tags: modeling, uv, edges, customization

It's looks like there is a setting to manage it, but I don't know where is it.

When I edit UV's, Blender automatically adds Sharp Edges on the boundaries of islands. How can I disable it?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide your .blend file?

Comment: Huh, was able to reproduce.  It's a bug, and you should consider a bug report.  To prevent it from happening, unhide the rest of your mesh (or if you want, just unhide the verts adjacent to the ones you're editing.)

Comment: wow, it's looks like a fixed bug, affects 2.91 but not 2.92...